# How to receive data in Flask container from node container?

Tags: node.js, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm trying to receive data sent from a node.js application to a flask application, both running inside their own docker containers, networked using docker-compose.

Here is my flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

# Server connection information
host = ""  # Might need to make this empty when service is dockerized.
port = 65432

# Set up flask server
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/inbound_message', methods=['POST'])
def inbound_message():
    data = request.get_json()

    received_message = data['message']
    print(received_message)

    welcome_message = "Hi, thanks for getting in touch! I'm currently a work in progress - please check back soon!"

    response_message = welcome_message

    return json.dumps({"response_message": response_message})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=port)
```

Here is the function being called in my node application:

```
async function inboundMessage(message) {

    const data = {
        message: message
    };

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://ai-core:65432/inbound_message',
        body: data,
        json: true
    };

    return await request(options)

        .then(function (parsedBody) {
            return parsedBody['response_message'];
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
}
```

And my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ai-webserver:
    container_name: ai-webserver
    build:
      context: './web_server'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - ai-services
    links:
      - 'ai-core:ai-core'

  ai-core:
    container_name: ai-core
    build:
      context: './core'
    ports:
      - '65432:65432'
    networks:
      - ai-services

networks:
  ai-services:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

The error I'm getting from the node application is 'RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.3:65432'. I'm unsure why this isn't working, as it works fine when the applications aren't running inside a container, which suggests its just an issue with the networking of the containers. I tried moving from individual containers over to docker-compose with a docker network, but I'm unsure if I've done this correctly. I've tried a few different uri's in the node.js function without any success.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: The default Flask configuration is unreachable from outside its own container, whether from the host via `ports:` or another container via Docker networking.  You need to set `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` to make it accessible.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your advice! Unfortunately I've tried this and had no joy. It still gives me the same connection error.